# Testing for autocorrelation in model with categorical variable

Tags: r, time-series, mixed-model, autocorrelation, variogram

I have an `lme` model with a significant categorical variable. I have recently been advised to test for autocorrelation in the residuals of that model separately for each level of that variable. The result is that some levels show autocorrelation and some don't and I am not able to deal with this autocorrelation by specifying relevant correlation structures.

I am not entirely sure, whether it is really necessary to perform these tests independently. For illustration, I have attached an fairly random example, using the `sp::meuse` data set. Any opinions will be much appreciated!

```
easypackages::libraries("sp", "tidyverse", "gstat")

data("meuse")

mod <- lm(lead ~ soil*elev, data = meuse)
summary(mod)
meuse$E1 <- resid(mod)

coordinates(meuse) <- c("x", "y")

###separate tests
v1 <- variogram(E1 ~ x + y, data = meuse[meuse$soil == "1",]) %>% 
  mutate(soil = "1")
v1.fit <- fit.variogram(v1, vgm(psill = 8000,
                                model = "Sph",
                                range = 1500,
                                nugget = 2000)) 
vario_line1 <- variogramLine(v1.fit, maxdist = 1800) %>%
  mutate(soil = "1")
v2 <- variogram(E1 ~ x + y, data = meuse[meuse$soil == "2",]) %>% 
  mutate(soil = "2")
v2.fit <- fit.variogram(v2, vgm(psill = 3000,
                                model = "Sph",
                                range = 1200,
                                nugget = 500)) 
vario_line2 <- variogramLine(v2.fit, maxdist = 1800) %>%
  mutate(soil = "2")
v3 <- variogram(E1 ~ x + y, data = meuse[meuse$soil == "3",]) %>% 
  mutate(soil = "3")
v3.fit <- fit.variogram(v3, vgm(psill = 300,
                                model = "Sph",
                                range = 50,
                                nugget = 10)) 
vario_line3 <- variogramLine(v3.fit, maxdist = 1800) %>%
  mutate(soil = "3")

mrg_fit <- rbind(v1, v2, v3)
mrg_line <- rbind(vario_line1, vario_line2, vario_line3)

ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = dist, y = gamma), data = mrg_fit) +
  geom_line(aes(x = dist, y = gamma), data = mrg_line, color = "blue") +
  facet_wrap(~soil, scales = "free_y") +
  labs(x = "Distance", y = "Semi-variogram")
```

[image: seperate]

```
###combined test
v <- variogram(E1 ~ x + y, data = meuse) 
v.fit <- fit.variogram(v, vgm(psill = 8000,
                                model = "Sph",
                                range = 1500,
                                nugget = 2000)) 
vario_line <- variogramLine(v.fit, maxdist = 1800) %>%
  mutate(soil = "1")

ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = dist, y = gamma), data = v) +
  geom_line(aes(x = dist, y = gamma), data = vario_line, color = "blue") +
  labs(x = "Distance", y = "Semi-variogram")
```

[image: combined]